# Magento - UnitTests - Mock Objects

Tags: php, unit-testing, magento, mocking

I am writing some tests for a Magento module, using [Ivan Chepurnyi's extension](http://www.ecomdev.org/2011/02/10/new-version-of-ecomdev_phpunit-0-1-2-extension-for-magento.html), and I'm having trouble using the mock objects.
Here is the class:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Block_Class extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    private $_salesCollection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_salesCollection = Mage::getModel('module/classA')->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('id', $this->_getId());
    }

    public function _getId()
    {
        return Mage::getModel('module/classB')->getId();//session params
    }

    public function getSalesTotalNumber()
    {
        return $this->_salesCollection->count();
    }
}
```

The method I'm trying to test is **getSalesTotalNumber()**.
And here is the test:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Test_Block_Class extends EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case
{
    private $_mock;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->_mock = $this->getMock('Namespace_Module_Block_Class',
                                        array('_getId')
                                      );
        $this->_mock->expects($this->any())
                    ->method('_getId')
                    ->will($this->returnValue(1024));

        parent::setUp();
    }

    /**
     * @test
     * @loadFixture
     * @loadExpectation
     */
    public function testSalesTotalNumber()
    {
        $actual = $this->_mock->getSalesTotalValue();
        $expected = $this->_getExpectations()->getSalesTotalNumber();

        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }
}
```

As you can see, what I want to do is overwrite the **_getId()** method so that it returns an id which match the id in the fixture and so load the collection. But it doesn't work :-(.

In my test, if I echo `$this->_mock->_getId()` it returns the correct Id (1024). But in the `__construct()` of my class `$this->_getId()` returns null, which is the *expected* value during testing (I mean, during testing there is no session, so it can't get the object's Id as I store it in a session variable). So the **_getId()** method isn't *mocked* by my test case.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, the prolem was not in the mock but in the class structure. I've deleted the `__construct()` and move his content to a private method which returns the collection object: my test passes and I have a better, decooupled class. I love TDD :D

Comment: You might consider answering your own question so other can find it more easily. It's perfectly allowed. At the moment it is classified under "unanswered"

Comment: That's true Peter, here you go :)

Comment: Hey David, why you don't use $this->getModelMock() and replaceByMock() methods?

Comment: @Ivan, basically because I didn't they existed :), I'll look into it for my next mock. thx for your interest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So my problem was not in the mock/test but in the class.
I have moved the content of `__construct()` into a protected method which returns the collection object. That's how my class looks like now:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Block_Class extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    private $_salesCollection;

    protected function _getAffiliateSales()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_salesCollection)) {
            $affiliateId = $this->_getId();
            $this->_salesCollection = Mage::getModel('module/classA')
                                ->addFieldToFilter('id', $affiliateId);
        }
        return $this->_salesCollection;
    }

    public function _getId()
    {
        return Mage::getModel('module/classB')->getId();//session params
    }

    public function getSalesTotalNumber()
    {
        return $this->_getAffiliateSales()->count();
    }
}
```